# Updating Component State from Helper Component

Tags: javascript, react-native, state, chat, helper

I know there are tons of solutions for this using Redux and other state management packages, but for the purpose of my project, I'm not really relying on a lot of state change

[image: App Diagram]

Now my issue lies in the following; I'm logging the user in using several APIs, one of which is a chat API. The helper logs the user in and then sets its own state with two objects returned.

On the Chat page, in the render() function I have conditionals for certain elements to be rendered based on the presence of the two states returned from the helper library, if they exist pass them as props to child components.

I understand I can use globals to set a global.chatReady from the Helper and just use that, but since the login takes some time, if the page is loaded before the global.chatReady is set I would need to navigate away to update the UI.

There is no link between the Helper and Chat and I'm not sharing any states using react-navigation.

Any ideas? o.O

Comment: Several ideas. Context api. Lift up the state and drill down props. Drill down the setter of the state as callback and trigger it from the deeper child component. You have several ways to handle this problem, find out the solution which is most appropriate for you project. I highly discourage you from using a state management library just for this goal

Answer (score 1):

Create a state in app component , something `isChatHelperReady`, pass it down the Chat component, also pass down an update `isChatHelperReady` method to login component from app component.  In login component after import helper library, update the `isChatHelperReady` state in app component using the method